Make the background of a 8-bit monchrome gray image be transparent
Done so far
I have created an 8-bit monochrome Gray image drawn a closed path on it and then filled the closed path with pixels having a 0x44 value. The code is below.

import (
    "image"

    "app/slicer/renderer/gray/drawgray"
)

    // Initialize the graphic context on a gray image
    dest := image.NewGray(image.Rect(0, 0, 297, 210.0))
    gc := drawgray.NewGraphicContext(dest)

    // Set some properties
    gc.SetFillColor(0x44) // Any integer from 0 to 255

    // Draw a closed shape
    gc.BeginPath() // Initialize a new path
    gc.MoveTo(0, 0)
    gc.LineTo(100, 0)
    gc.LineTo(100, 100)
    gc.LineTo(0, 100)
    gc.Close()
    gc.Fill()

    // Save to file
    drawgray.SaveToPngFile("test1--drawgray.png", dest)


Result
The resulting image is as follows:

Question
Transparent background?
The resulting image above makes sense ✔️
But I have one question about the image background. As can be seen, the pixels outside the path are black. They are not transparent. Maybe it's expected for the image.Gray to have a default black background. Since for each pixel, there is only 1 byte of color info. There is no info regarding the alpha or transparency. Am I right? I'm not sure 
Is there a way to make the pixels outside the drawn path be transparent rather than black? By any chance.

"image.Gray represents an 8-bit grayscale color" -- there's no alpha channel, hence there is no transparency.

You can make black pixels transparent "ex post facto" with ImageMagick. Use magick INPUT.PNG -transparent black RESULT.PNG in your Terminal.

@MarkSetchell Thanks. I wonder whether the RESULT.PNG would be an RGBA image or a Gray/monochrome image? Probably RGBA, right?

The result is a palette image (i.e. indexed) with PNG colortype=3.  You can force RGBA8888 if you want, change RESULT.PNG to PNG32:RESULT.PNG

Of course, you could generate the entire image with ImageMagick too magick -size 297x210 xc:none -fill "gray(68)" -draw "rectangle 0,0 100,100" result.png

PNG solves this by marking one particular color as transparent. http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html#png.ch08.div.5.4 . Not that it answers anything specifically but just to note that there are other solutions to transparency than having an alpha channel.

As commented by @JimB :

"image.Gray represents an 8-bit grayscale color" -- there's no alpha channel, hence there is no transparency.

